# Trouble with nested matrices

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, matrices

I have tried repeatedly to google for the solution to this problem.
I have a matrix that looks like this.
[image]

But I want it to look like this.
[image]

Notice how the B, C, D and E are "very tightly centered" around the A.
Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\matt}[5] {
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ c c c }
\begin{bmatrix}
2+r & -1  \\
-1  & 2+r & -1 \\
    & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
    &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
\end{bmatrix} & {#3} &  \\ 
{#4} & {#1} & {#2} \\ 
 & {#5} & \begin{bmatrix}
2+r & -1  \\
-1  & 2+r & -1 \\
    & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
    &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
\end{bmatrix} \\ 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
$
}


\matt {A} {B} {C} {D} {E}

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Bob.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Nice question indeed! However, (with my mathematics typesetter hat on) I don't think you hould do that if $C$, $D$, $B$ and $F$ are matrices or vectors and not numbers.

Comment: Ah .. but for my need, they are just C, D, etc. Sometimes I need Z_n or Z_{n+1} .. but that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `adjustbox` to get the right vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox}

\newenvironment{Pbmatrix}[1][c]
 {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=#1}$\begin{bmatrix}}
 {\end{bmatrix}$\end{adjustbox}}

\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{Pbmatrix}[b]
  2+r & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r & -1 \\
      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
  \end{Pbmatrix} & #3 \\
  \hfill #4 & #1 & #2\hfill \\ 
  & #5 & \begin{Pbmatrix}[t]
    2+r & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r & -1 \\
        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
    \end{Pbmatrix}
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\begin{document}

\[
\matt {A} {B} {C} {D} {E}
\]

\end{document}
```

The auxiliary `Pbmatrix` environment has an alignment optional argument to get `t`op or `b`ottom alignment.

[image]

Comment: Could you show me how to resize the entire matrix so that it is 90% of its size? It is now too wide for my page.

Comment: @BobZigon You can always do `\scalebox{.9}{$\matt{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}$}` (with the `graphicx` package), but I probably would give a symbolic name to the matrix in the corners.

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is what you can do with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}rcl@{}}
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[b]
  2+r & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r & -1 \\
      & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots \\
      &        & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
  \end{bNiceMatrix} & C \\
  D & A & B \\ 
  & E & \begin{bNiceMatrix}[t]
    2+r & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r & -1 \\
        & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots \\
        &        & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r  \\    
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
  \end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]